# Data Detection and Editable (These attributes are mutually exclusive)

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I'm seeing this warning in a project and not sure what is causing it:
/Main_iPhone.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Data Detection and Editable (These attributes are mutually exclusive)

Ideas?

Answer (score 15):

This warning occurs due to the Textview. If you have taken Textview in storyboard and You have checked DataDetector type like Phone Number, Link and so on option in a storyboard when Behaviour "Editable" is enabled.

**- If "Editable" mode is enabled and you have checked the Phone Number, Link and other option.**

**- If "Editable" mode is enabled then DataDetector type works by default.**

**Solutions:**

**1. If "Editable" is enabled then UNCHECK all the DataDetector type option.**

**Note:** *If warning NOT goes then Please Delete Textview, clean the code and Add the Textview. Because some time it's cache is available in Xcode. Hope it will helps.*

Happy Coding.. :)

TextView with DataDetector option:
[image]

Comment: Funny, because "Link" seems to be a default. I am pretty sure I didn't select it.